# Why did I get banned from posting on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, post-ban, ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

About a month ago I got banned from Stack Overflow. You know, this kind of ban:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

And from the link they provided, it appears that's there's no timeout. You just have to do something, a huge gap increase in reputation, etc.

The sad thing is that I only had gotten -8 and another -8 on a question, but other than that, my reputation was pretty good (no other downvotes on my questions), and I've answered quite a few questions, a lot of them being accepted answers. I'm surprised that this triggered a ban of this toughness. I wasn't a spammer or anything!

Since then, I've really tried to earn a lot of reputation, like I earned +100, but I still aren't allowed to post, and besides a lot of your reputation is from asking and accepting questions, so it's really hard. :(

Besides, it's kind of hard to help so many people without the motivation that they will be helping you too with your questions.

I've got so many questions that are stalling my project that I can't ask on Stack Overflow.

Is there anything I can do? :(

Comment: Yes, two -8s can do that. The ban isn't tied to reputation. So you'll have to start by improving those.

Comment: @Mysticial yes, it is tied to rep http://goo.gl/C1Kwu . I also edited my question for clarity.

Comment: @Mysticial Besides, how do I fix those? They were posted a while ago, and are now closed. And I can't post new questions with more upvotes to rectify them!

Comment: AFAIK, it's not tied to the rep *number*. It just that gaining rep by posting good answers will help you out of the ban. It's the posts, not the rep.

Comment: @Mysticial As I explained in the question, I DID post more answers with upvotes. Hey look at my StackOverflow profile. It says it there.

Comment: This is simply a hold to prevent more questions until the ones you have already asked get improved (as voted on by the community) - you are not banned in using the site for any other actions. You can read a lot about the why, how and steps you can take on [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).

Comment: @bmike the problem is that my posts will probably never get more upvotes improved. Because they're locked and closed a long time ago,. I doubt that a huge amount of people would go back in time and look at a locked question with a lot of downvotes, and for no reason upvote. Especially if the question wasn't amazing (admittedly).

Comment: @DumbSearch Ouch - you can work on editing a closed question, but not a locked one. Have you considered either a) flagging one of the locked questions asking for moderator to undelete it so you could work on improving it (mentioning that you recognize how in the past you asked some bad questions, but show examples of the good ones I saw on your account). Perhaps there is a way with assistance to rehabilitate old contributions. Also, you could ask for a feature request for a process to age away past bad contributions - especially if you can show good participation on a related site.

Comment: @DumbSearch none of your questions appear to be locked, meaning that they can still be edited to improve them.  Once this was done you could flag them to be re-opened.  They still wouldn't appear on the front page due to their -8 but once reopened you could set a bounty on them to draw attention to your now improved question.

Comment: @Rory alright thanks. :) I'll try it out

Comment: @bmike alright thanks a lot for your help. :) I'll try it out

Comment: I can't find a way of setting a bounty for my closed question... :( So how do I get people to reopen it?

Comment: You voted to reopen it? (someone did at least) Then it should be appearing in the reopen queue. If that doesn't work out, you can later on flag for moderator attention. They can then evaluate if it's worth it to reopen.

Comment: @Bart ok thanks. :) Yes, I voted for reopening it. How do you flag fag for moderator attention?

Comment: Next to the "reopen" link, there is a "flag" link. You can choose a custom flag reason and explain what it is you want. But give this reopening by the community a day at least.

Comment: @Bart wow thanks your great. :P :)

Comment: @Mysticial ban is now lifted, and my closed question is no longer closed! :-) I'm so happy! Thanks everybody who made this possible!

Comment: @Bart my ban is now lifted, and my closed question is no longer closed! :-) I'm so happy! Thanks everybody who made this possible!

Comment: @Rory my ban is now lifted, and my closed question is no longer closed! :-) I'm so happy! Thanks everybody who made this possible!

Comment: @DumbSearch Congrats, keep it up.

Comment: @Bart It was actually you who made it possible! :-) By suggesting to un-close my bad questions by improving. :) It's ironic that this question is now closed, though :D